Docker build succeeds on one system but not on other
System info
I've been Dockerizing an application on System A, which is a Debian 12 clean installation, AMD64 architecture. The system info:
Linux debian12.localdomain 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm

On System B which is our production server, the image fails to build on the same architecture. Server info:
Linux server 5.10.0-28-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.209-2 (2024-01-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

I should also note that on a Windows 11 installation with WSL2, the image also builds just fine. WSL2 info:
Linux DESKTOP-X 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Jan 11 04:09:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 Linux
Build failure
The build fails on second line:
FROM python:3.9 as venv

RUN python3 -m venv venv

With this error:
------
 > [app venv 4/5] RUN python3 -m venv venv:
9.811 Error: Command '['/usr/src/app/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 -m venv venv" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I've searched and I can understand where this error is coming from. Some answers suggest to run sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv but I'm reluctant to use this, I'm using the official Python docker image after all, and it builds fine on 2 machines. Some other answers suggest to run python3 -m venv venv --without-pip but I need pip!
I really thought I should ask this because I'm baffled how an image builds on one machine and not on the other, from the same base image.
And one funny thing is if on the production server I do sudo docker run --name testpy -it python:3.9 /bin/bash and inside the temporary container run python3 -m venv venv the command finishes successfully!
How can I fix this? Where does this issue come from?
Note1: I've multiple times tried pruning the whole system and rebuilding using docker system prune -a and docker compose up -d
Note2: Pushing built images to a repo is not an option for us unfortunately.
Related Docker links:
https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/j6tgyu/image_built_in_different_machine_fails/
https://forums.docker.com/t/baffled-dockerfile-builds-on-all-but-one-of-our-teams-computers/130642
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871728/same-docker-image-works-on-one-machine-and-fails-on-the-other
https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/100h41r/why_is_docker_not_working_with_python_venvs/
Related Python links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594088/error-when-creating-venv-error-command-im-ensurepip-upgrade-def
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268833/error-command-path-to-env-bin-python3-7-im-ensurepip-upgrade
